# How to update my sql 5.0 query

Tags: mysql

I have following sql query:

```
UPDATE table_b
SET score=1, score_a = 1
WHERE id = (select id from table_a where user_id ="Ken")
```

I want to update score and score_a for more then one user like "Ken", "Joe", etc.

Can anyone help me tell how can that be done?

Answer (score 4):

Use a `JOIN` joining `table_b.id` to `table_a.id`.

```
UPDATE
  table_b
  JOIN table_a ON table_b.id = table_a.id
SET 
  score=1, 
  score_a = 1
WHERE
  table_a.user_id IN('Ken','Joe','etc')
```